# Weird behaviour Datediff java Datediff sql

Tags: java, t-sql, datetime

when I try to calculate the difference between two dates in seconds in java I get a different output than in sql.

SQL:

```
select DATEDIFF(second, 
                 convert(datetime, '2014-01-07 11:00:27', 120), 
                 convert(datetime, '2018-07-09 00:00:00', 120))
```

=> 142001973

```
    SimpleDateFormat NORM_DATE_TO_STRING = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date reference = NORM_DATE_TO_STRING.parse("2014-01-07 11:00:27");

    Date we =  NORM_DATE_TO_STRING.parse("2018-07-09 00:00:00");

    long diff = (we.getTime()-reference.getTime())/1000;
```

=> 141998373

Its off by one hour and I dont know why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Such a difference would normally be explained by time zone issues such as daylight-savings time.  One system is probably converting to local date/time and the other to UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java version takes daylight savings time into account, and the SQL one doesn't.